# Progressbar is not updated during runtime

Tags: python

I'm new here and I'm trying to learn Python. I have a problem with updating my progressbar during the printing of values. At the end of counting *i* to 100, my progressbar is directly updating from 0 to 100. Is it possible to update the progressbar after every printing of a value? My goal is it to see how far the count has progressed. This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def step():
    progressbar['value']=0
    for i in range(1,100):
        print(i)
        progressbar['value']+=20

master=Tk()

progressbar=ttk.Progressbar(master,orient="horizontal",length=300,mode="determinate")
progressbar['maximum']=100
progressbar.pack()

button=Button(master,text="Count",command=step)
button.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

I would be very grateful if someone would help me with this problem.

Comment: Why are doing `+=20` inside `for i in range(1,100):` rather than `+=1`? You will finally get  `1980` which is far beyond your maximum of `100`.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right. I forgot to change 20 into 1. The last version of my code had a for-loop which counted to 5.

Answer (score 1):

*At the end of counting i to 100, my progressbar is directly updating from 0 to 100.*

There is distinct possiblity that it does, but it is so fast you are unable to see it. Please add `import time` and replace

```
def step():
    progressbar['value']=0
    for i in range(1,100):
        print(i)
        progressbar['value']+=20
```

using

```
def step():
    progressbar['value']=0
    for i in range(1,100):
        print(i)
        progressbar['value']+=1
        time.sleep(1.0)
```

Then run your code and write if progress bar does go smoothly from 0 to 100 or still it does jump to 100?

Comment: Unfortunately only the numbers are printed but the progressbar is not loaded, only at the end it loads again directly from 0 to 100

Answer (score 0):

This will do it.

```
# coding: utf-8
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time

master = Tk() # I have taken this one to start of program.

def step():
    progressbar['value']=0
    for i in range(1,100):
        print(i)
        progressbar['value']+=1
        master.update_idletasks()  # Update all the geometry related tasks etc. and calls all pending tasks. You require this too with time.
        time.sleep(0.05)  # Lesser value means fast, higher value means slow

progressbar=ttk.Progressbar(master,orient="horizontal",length=300,mode="determinate")
progressbar['maximum']=100
progressbar.pack()

button=Button(master,text="Count",command=step)
button.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

Output: [image: There you go 3/4th of the way]

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it :)

Comment: Yes, the `master.update_idletasks()` part is important with time delay as per your choice. Anyways, happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

Reaction to the answer of Daweo:

[image]

As you can see here, my window freezes during the printing of values.